# How do I solve this cyclic logarithmic equation?

Tags: logarithms

$$5^{\log_2 x}+2x^{\log_5 2}=15$$
I have also noticed, that logarithmic terms are cyclic and tried to express one as y to make it easier, but still had no luck solving it. Any help?

Comment: i think a numerical method will help you

Comment: I don't think I know this topic yet. How about solving it using only basic properties of logarithms?

Comment: i think this doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure about the equation ? Check for typos.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the equation as

$$x^{\log_25}+2x^{\log_52}=15,$$or with $t=x^{\log_25}$,

$$t+2t^{\log_5^22}=15.$$

There is a single root near $x=2.8988$, with no closed-form expression.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$a^{\log_cb}=b^{\log_ca}$$
SO
$$5^{\log_2 x}+2x^{\log_5 2}=x^{\log_2 5}+2x^{\log_5 2}=15$$

Let us call $y=\log_25$
So$$x^y+2x^{1/y}=15$$

which has a solution at

$$x\approx2.898813156$$